# "Like I said..." in Chinese

Tags: word-requests

How do I say "Like I said...", or "As I said", in Chinese. For example:

> A: I've never been to China.
>
> B: What do you think of Chinese culture?
>
> A: Like I said, I've never been to China.

Comment: Trideceth, can you please show what you tried before asking? As per the [FAQ], requesting translations without showing effort is off topic. :) It's ok if you didn't find anything, but at least show it! :P

Comment: @Alenanno I reckon "translation" refers to whole phrases, whereas this is about a specific idiom :) I would agree if I had asked for a translation of an entire phrase.  Plus.. we need many many more questions per day if we want to pass beta (bad excuse but I know... but we do :D

Comment: Actually I gave it a thought after I asked, and yes, in your case the rule is less strict, as I don't think there are many places where to look for idioms, but you know, it's good to see some effort anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a full translation of your conversation.

> A: 我从没去过中国。
>   B: 你对中国文化有什么看法
>   A: 正如我说过的，我从没去过中国。

As you can see, "like I said" is "正如我说过的" in Chinese. A word-to-word translation would be

> "like"  ⟶ "正如/就如/就像"
>    I      ⟶ "我"
>   "said"  ⟶ "说过的".

Answer (score 1):

A direct way of saying it would be “我说了”, though it sometimes suggests that the speaker is impatient/angry or high in the social hierarchy (teachers, bosses, etc).

Comment: Kejia, do you mind expanding on your answer? For example, why this expression? What does it have more than others?

Comment: Mostly nonsense. He is complaining about the at-least-30-characters-rule.

Comment: After the edit by gonnastop, this answer seems to be the most natural/native way. the more impatient/angry way is `我不是说了吗！`.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggested translation would be 像我刚说的 (as I just said) or 像我说过的 (as I have said).